# Selenium / Python - Fill in the login in a pop-up window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to fill in the login of this page with selenium: https://influence.co/go/location-search/top-nl-influencers/city/amsterdam. But it is not sending the keys.

Send_keys

```
try:
     email = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#user_email")
     self.assertTrue(email.is_enabled)
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", email)
     email.send_keys('email@gmail.com')

except:
     print("Problem")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one match for that locator. Email field is the second one, so you have to mention like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@id='user_email'])[2]").send_keys("email@gmail.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

I count four elements with id of user_email on the page.  One approach is to wait until the modal dialog for new users appears (a few seconds):

```
    welcome_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#welcome-mat form#new_user")))
    email = WebDriverWait(welcome_form, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#user_email")))
    # set email
    email.send_keys("sa.sarvan@gmail.com")
    password = welcome_form.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#user_password")
    # set password
    password.send_keys("PASSWORD")
    display_pwd  = welcome_form.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.hideShowPassword-toggle")
    # display password
    display_pwd.click()
    WebDriverWait(welcome_form, 2).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_attribute((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.hideShowPassword-toggle"), "class", "hideShowPassword-toggle-hide"))
    # hide password
    display_pwd.click()
```